coplanar waveguide impedance calculation and tolerance
The Ublox Sara R5 System Integration Guide I am following states that a 50 Ohm antenna waveguide design is recommended and provides a couple example designs that achieve this using FR4 dielectric.

However when I calculate the impedance from these designs they are and 57.1ohm and 59.7ohm. Am I making a calculation mistake or is there generally loose tolerance when it comes to achieving 50ohm?



Is the fact that you have air above the trace and FR4 below it messing you up?

And most co-planar waveguide structures I've come across have a GND-SIG-GND stackup, so that you have a GND plane above & below the signal trace.

@SteveSh I've used CPW on the top layer many times. It isn't restricted to inner layers, and the AppCAD screen shot doesn't seem to be assuming a buried layer. (Also, why use CPW on an inner layer when stripline would also give good field confinement in less space?)

@OP, on pg 69 of the document you linked they mention their design uses "FR4 dielectric substrate material with 4.3 typical permittivity at 1 GHz, and 0.013 typical
loss tangent at 1 GHz. " But you assumed a Dk of 4.6. What happens to the AppCAD calculations if you use their value for the Dk of FR4?

OK, just tried it myself and changing Dk to 4.3 makes the discrepancy even worse. My guess is that they used HFSS (where you can account for things like etching factors and surface roughness) rather than AppCAD to optimize their design, but you'd have to ask somebody at ublox to be sure.

@The Photon - Do you really think surface roughness is a factor at 1 GHz, OP's stated frequency.

@SteveSh, OK, probably not. But there are enough dials to turn when setting up a model in HFSS that you can easily get a different result for the same geometry.
